# Hive multiple subqueries

Tags: subquery, hive

I'm using Hive 0.9.0 and I'm trying to execute query i.e.

```
`SELECT a.id, b.user FROM (SELECT...FROM a_table) a, (SELECT...FROM b_table) b WHERE a.date   = b.date;`
```

but it returns error "loop (...)+ does not match input....".
Does Hive support multiple subqueries in FROM just like Oracle DB?

Answer (score 6):

Multiple [subqueries](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-subqueries.html) allowed in hive.

I tested with below code,it works.

```
    select * from (select id from test where id>10) a 
join (select id from test where id>20) b on a.id=b.id;
```

Please post your exact code so that I can give relevant solution.

Comment: thanks, Balaswamy! I've already did the query with JOIN just like in your example

Answer (score 1):

join subqueries is supported Absolutely.

I think the key problem is that u use `SELECT...FROM`.

The correct syntax is `SELECT * FROM`

```
SELECT a.id, b.user 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM a_table) a 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM b_table) b ON a.date = b.date;
```

Comment: I'm presuming the ... is meant to be shorthand for "some fields"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain the full Cartesian product before applying the WHERE
clause, instead:

```
SELECT a.id, b.user FROM (SELECT...FROM a_table) a, (SELECT...FROM b_table) b WHERE a.date   = b.date;
```

you should use 'join' in the middle, i.e.

```
SELECT a.id, b.user FROM (SELECT...FROM a_table) a join (SELECT...FROM b_table) b WHERE a.date   = b.date;
```

above is not admissible in strict mode.